# Will Unicoin-based questions be cleaned up

Tags: discussion, unicoins

What does Stack Overflow plan to do with Unicoin-based questions on both meta and the main site?

Is the extra rep gained on questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789277/unicoin-mining-and-canvas-clicking) a gift from the unicorns or will it be removed and cleaned?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, any reason for the down-vote?

Comment: I gave you an upvote to cancel out any of the ill will.

Comment: *Some* of the questions which are completely fabricated nonsense will be. But that's a very small percentage of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for the cleanup. Temporary features (for example winterbash) are part of the SE network and as such deserve full support.

Comment: What about on the main site? The question referred to by the OP would have been closed and severely downvoted had it not been related to Unicoins.

Comment: The question was on topic yesterday. And should possibly be kept for historical purposes.